# How to show f' is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The problem is as following: Let $f$ be differentiable over $[a,b]$, show $f^{\prime}$ is measurable. Anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Measurable with respect to which measure?

Comment: What is that mean?

Comment: We can't talk about measurability without stating what the measurable sets are, right?

Comment: Sorry , I mean On Lebesgue, I just started learn measure theory, I thought every measurable are in Lebesgue measurable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean Lebesgue measurable. As a matter of convenience, let us extend $f$ to a function on $\mathbb{R}$ by setting $f(x)=f(a)$ for $x<a$ and $f(x)=f(b)$ for $x>b$.

For each $n\geq 1$, define
$$ h_n(x)=\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}} $$
Each $h_n$ is measurable since $f$ is measurable, and since $\lim_{n\to\infty}h_n(x)=f^{\prime}(x)$ almost everywhere, it follows that $f^{\prime}$ is measurable as well.

Comment: Why is the  limn→∞hn(x)=f′(x)?

Comment: By the definition of the derivative: $f^{\prime}(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. Take $h=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I got it!! It's so easy now.....Thank you!

Comment: Excuse me, another problem. Do you mean f(x)=f(a) for x>a and f(x)=f(b) for x<b, because the function is over [a,b]

Comment: No, I think it's correct as written. I'm extending $f$ to be constant on $(-\infty,a]$ and $[b,\infty)$. It's not really important, it's just a way to ensure $h_n$ is always defined.

Comment: Alright, I got it!